# Using wildcard characters in Windows command prompt

Tags: command, wildcard, command-prompt

I was wondering if it is possible to use wildcard characters in Windows Command Prompt. 
For example, if I want to see all files in a directory ending with .docx, on Linux I would type this `ls *.docx`. Is there a similar tool in Windows?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, wildcards work, in a very similar way. The Windows equivalent would be `dir *.docx`.

Comment: What if I want to print all .docx files in a directory, will this work too?

Comment: Yes, that works, though `print` is only good for text files.

Comment: I am using this command to print .docx files ""C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office12/winword" C:/Users/username/Downloads/*.docx /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit"

Comment: Open a new question if you have extra things that need to be answered.  Questions are free, and SO is designed around a question and answer.

Answer (score 4):

yes you can.

e.g.

> The asterisk character, *, can stand in for any number of characters.
>   Some examples of this command:
>
> ```
> c:\>del *.doc
> ```
>
> This command would delete every file with the doc extension from the
>   root directory of C: . So files like myfile.doc, testfile.doc, and
>   123.doc would all be deleted.

refer to this link:

http://www.ahuka.com/?page_id=31

Comment: This appears to be something that the command is responsible for doing. If I do `java.exe -jar thisIsMyJar_*` when I have a file called `thisIsMyJar_1.0.jar`, Java spits out an error message: `Unable to access jarfile thisIsMyJar_*`. This is in contrast to most (all?) *nix shells where wildcards are handled after variables are expanded and before passing the arguments to the program that will be run.