# Don't know how to run on multiple files in windows

Tags: python, pycodestyle

This seems really simple and surely I am missing something obvious, but I can get pycodestyle to work with wildcards on my Mac but not on my pc.   What am I doing wrong ?

I have tried the following and it works on my Mac:

```
pycodestyle ./flaskr/*.py
pycodestyle --statistics ./flaskr/*.py
```

However this doesn't seem to work on a pc:

```
pycodestyle flaskr\*.py
pycodestyle "flaskr\*.py"
pycodestyle .\flaskr\*.py
pycodestyle ".\flaskr\*.py"
pycodestyle --statistics flaskr\*.py
pycodestyle --statistics .\flaskr\*.py
```

I expect a report or little output, but I tend to get something similar to the following:

```
E902 OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'flaskr\\*.py'
```

Comment: Related question: [Using wildcard characters in Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712649/using-wildcard-characters-in-windows-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

windows `cmd.exe` does not expand wildcards like POSIX shells do -- so globbing techniques will not work

in this case however, you're just trying to run on a single folder, which `pycodestyle` supports:

```
pycodestyle flaskr
```